# pyspark how to add selected columns based on value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For the below data structure, I hope to return a new dataframe base on the `condition` column. For example if `"condition" =='A'` the new dataframe should have cols values in group1, and if `"condition" =='B'` the new dataframe should have cols values in group2. The thing is I do not want to hard code the column names, as there could be many columns after `anothervalue`. How could I do this? Many thanks for your help. For example for this input dataframe,

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|condition|   group1|   group2|
+---------+---------+---------+
|        A|{SEA, WA}|{PDX, OR}|
|        B| {NY, NY}| {LA, CA}|
+---------+---------+---------+
```

I'd like to get this output:

```
+---------+---------+
|condition|   group |  
+---------+---------+
|        A|{SEA, WA}|
|        B| {LA, CA}|
+---------+---------+
```

The above input dataframe was created using this json schema:

```
jsonStrings = ['{"condition":"A","group1":{"city":"SEA","state":"WA"},"group2":{"city":"PDX","state":"OR"}}','{"condition":"B","group1":{"city":"NY","state":"NY"},"group2":{"city":"LA","state":"CA"}}']
```

Comment: any sample dataframe?

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Could you show it in dataframe format instead of json format, and could you also provide the expected output dataframe?

Comment: I edited the question with both example dataframe and json input.

Comment: why not just use `when`?

Comment: yes but my problem is, after `when(df.condition == "A", ` I am not sure how to select the nested columns under "group1" without specifying all the column names (ie city, state etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `when` and construct dynamic list of conditions as below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

conditions = when(col('condition') == 'A', col("group1"))\
    .when(col('condition') == 'B', col("group2")).otherwise(None)

df1.select(col('condition'), conditions.alias("group")).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------+
|condition|group    |
+---------+---------+
|A        |{SEA, WA}|
|B        |{LA, CA} |
+---------+---------+
```